# What is difference between tostring and getstringcellvalue?

Tags: apache, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

While reading a cell value of an excel i used the code snippet

```
cellValue=wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(cellNumber).getStringCellValue();
```

and also

```
`cellValue=wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(cellNumber).toString();`
```

both returns same data (i mean the value of cell) but what is the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 0):

See the basic definition of both

**getCell(1).toString**

`public String toString()`

Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Returns:

a string representation of the object.

**getCell(1).getStringCellValue()**

Get the value of the cell as a string

For numeric cells this will throw an exception. For blank cells this will return an empty string. For formulaCells that are not string Formulas, this will throws an exception.

Returns:
the value of the cell as a string

For example: If the cell contains Date field, and you use `toString()` you may get the correct date formatted value, but never get any exception, While in the second case, you will get `IllegalArgumentException`